# memoryError: out of memory

Tags: python

I wrote a program that download the app,movie and other.but when I run it that give me this  Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tidopy.py", line 27, in <module>
data=urllib2.urlopen(addresslist[x]).read()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 362, in read
  buf.write(data)
MemoryError: out of memory
```

I think that Error is about this code:

```
data=urllib2.urlopen(addresslist[x]).read()
file=open(namelist[x],'wb')
file.write(data)
```

data is a variable that downloads the data of movies and other

file makes a file

and file.write(data) puts the data in the file

tidopy is my program name..

How can I fix it?

help.

Comment: How much memory do you have? How big is the response you are expecting>?

Comment: The problem's not with your code - you're just downloading more data than your computer can handle. Try downloading and handling the data in smaller pieces.

Comment: how?may I write data in file line to line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you're downloading files from a url and writing it to a file, but during that you expect `data` to hold the entire file, which happens in your computer's memory (RAM of pagefile) which runs out, when the files are big (like movies).

The solution is to write each chunk of file as it is downloaded, and not to load the entire thing to memory and only then write it. I have a small code that does that, if you want to use it:

```
import requests # just a choice of comfort for me
def download(url_address, filename):
    response = requests.get(url_address, stream=True)
    response.raise_for_status()
    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        total_length = response.headers.get('content-length')
        if total_length is None:
            f.write(response.content)
        else:
            total_length = int(total_length)
            for data in response.iter_content(chunk_size = total_length / 100):
                f.write(data)
```

If you notice, i've set `chunk_size = total_length / 100` which means that every time the download in `data` reaches 1% it's writing to the file, and then it's replaced with the next 1% of data that comes in, so it always takes 1% of the data that is stored in memory. If the files you are downloading are too big to handle even for 1% in memory, you should replace the `chunk_size` to be a fixed number of bytes, maybe 1,000,000 (which is roughly 1 MB)

Comment: no when I had linux I used this program but when I install windows I got this Error

Comment: windows takes up more memory than linux, so there's less memory free to download large files. But even if you had 100 times more memory than you do now it would be very bad practice to load the entire large file into memory when you can write it piece by piece and free the memory of that burden. How do you think browsers or torrent clients download large files? By writing it chunk after chuck to disk, not by loading into memory